# Proper component styles composition with react-select V2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

We want to set up a base Select component with a common styling for a whole app. Unfortunately, at the moment there is a need for some small tweak, those styles would be ignored unless specifically prepared for it in the base component. This is what I came up with, but it's rather ugly and error prone in my opinion. So I am wondering if there is a better way I might have missed?

This approach would be especially painful if there would be a need for some sub-common component that uses base one but has its own enhancement styling that needs to be tweaked from a parent.

```
export interface ISelectControlProps<OptionType = {}>
  extends Props<OptionType> {
  width?: number
  minWidth?: number
}

const composeStyles = (outerStyles: StylesConfig = {}) => ({
  ...outerStyles,
  control: (base, state) => {
    const {
      selectProps: { width, minWidth },
    } = state
    const controlStyles = {
      ...base,
      border: `1px solid ${Colors.greyMiddle}`,
      margin: Spacing.MarginAroundFormComponents,
      width: width !== undefined ? `${width}rem` : '100%',
      minWidth: minWidth !== undefined ? `${minWidth}rem` : '8rem',
    }
    return outerStyles.control
      ? outerStyles.control(controlStyles, state)
      : controlStyles
  },
  menu: (base, state) => {
    const {
      selectProps: { width },
    } = state
    const menuStyles = {
      ...base,
      zIndex: 20,
      color: Colors.black,
      width: width !== undefined ? `${width}rem` : '100%',
    }
    return outerStyles.menu ? outerStyles.menu(menuStyles, state) : menuStyles
  },
})

export class SelectControl<OptionType> extends React.Component<
  ISelectControlProps<OptionType>
> {
  render() {
    return <Select {...this.props} styles={composeStyles(this.props.styles)} />
  }
}
```

Notice that from the component itself I am grabbing any styles that were passed from parent and using them for composition with our base styles.

## Update

I've prepared a codesandbox example. It works, but in case of BaseSelect it just feels rather ugly and there was a lot of headache to figure how to assemble it there. Note that colors are intentionally ugly just to show the case :)

https://codesandbox.io/s/zk6jpnm613

Comment: Could you provide a specific example of the use case you describe ? thanks

Comment: @Laura Yes, I've prepared codesandbox example, see OP.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer but in your case I don't see any "cleaner" way to do it unfortunately